# Problem installing GTK in Code:Blocks (WIndows 10 )

Tags: compiler-errors, windows-10, gtk, codeblocks, linker-errors

After a serious Windows 10 crash, I have to re-format my disk and to re-install everything on my computer, but I remain unable to re-install GTK on Code:Blocks.

The version of Code:Blocks is the last one available (20.03) but I want to install the 2.24 version of GTK.

GTK is apparently correctly installed (after pkg-config; and gtk-demo works fine). I've correctly declared (I think) in Code:Blocks directories and libraries. However, I remain unable to compile my codes, and get the following error messages:

> ld.exe||cannot find -lgtk-win32-2.0|
> ld.exe||cannot find-lgobject-2.0|
> ld.exe||cannot find -lglib-2.0|

These libraries are in gtk/lib, which is declared in Code:Blocks.

This is now driving me crazy..

Thanks for any help on that & cheers,

Eric.

Comment: Just for the curiosity, why would you still working with GTK2 specially when GTK4 is almost out?

Comment: I'm planning to upgrade this, but I have already several thousands of code lines written, that use GTK2. So, for the moment at least, I need to remain in GTK2..

Answer (score 1):

I finally find out where the problem was. The GTK library I wanted to use (already compiled) is a 32 bits version, while the compiler that comes with the last version of Code:Blocks is a 64 bits version of gcc. It took me days to identify this problem.

I just got back to an older version of Cod:Blocks (with a 32 bits gcc version), and everything is solved now..

In the case it serves for others,

Eric.